# Is it possible to make a shortcut working while the window is not active/minimized in python?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I used PyQt5 to set a shortcut to a button.

`self.but2.setShortcut('Ctrl+Shift+Y')`

As long as the window is active in Windows, the shotcut works just fine, but when I deselect or minimize the window, the shortcut stops working.
Is it possible to make this shortcut working when the window is not active/minimized?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a library that detects inputs and activate the button using that.

You could use pynput:
https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

Here is an example, with code from https://pythonpyqt.com/pyqt-button/ and the pynput documentation, that toggles a pyQt close window button with your keyboard shortcut:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys
from pynput import keyboard


class PushButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PushButton")
        self.setGeometry(400,400,300,260)
        self.closeButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.closeButton.setText("Close")          #text
        self.closeButton.setIcon(QIcon("close.png")) #icon
        self.closeButton.setShortcut('Ctrl+D')  #shortcut key
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.closeButton.setToolTip("Close the widget") #Tool tip
        self.closeButton.move(100,100)

    def hotkey(self):
        def on_activate():
            self.closeButton.click()

        def for_canonical(f):
            return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

        hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
            keyboard.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<shift>+y'),
            on_activate)
        l = keyboard.Listener(
                on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
                on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)
        )
        l.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = PushButton()
    ex.show()
    ex.hotkey()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```